# Laravel - query builder to select multiple rows with unique column value (which has max value from another column)

Tags: database, postgresql, laravel

I have a table like this

```
data | usage_date | usage_hour
x    | 03/03/2016 | 05:30:30
y    | 03/02/2016 | 11:30:30
z    | 03/03/2016 | 07:30:30
p    | 03/02/2016 | 05:30:30
```

When I run Laravel query I would like see following rows being selected

```
y    | 03/02/2016 | 11:30:30
z    | 03/03/2016 | 07:30:30
```

So basically I want to build a query which will give unique values for 'usage_date', with max 'usage_hour'. How can I build this query?

Comment: I tried using ->max('usage_hour') But that fails with Grouping error: 7

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know how to do this in plain SQL, because Laravel's QueryBuilder is just a tool for building SQL-queries.

The task you described is kind of tricky and unfortunately there's no short and easy SQL query for that.

It can be done with [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT usage_date, 
    first_value(usage_hour) OVER (PARTITION BY usage_date ORDER BY usage_hour DESC) as usage_hour, 
    first_value(data) OVER (PARTITION BY usage_date ORDER BY usage_date DESC, usage_hour DESC) as data
FROM t
```

([sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ddeb/6))

With QueryBuilder it will look like this:

```
DB::table('t')
    ->distinct()
    ->select([
        'usage_date',
        DB::raw('first_value(usage_hour) OVER (PARTITION BY usage_date ORDER BY usage_hour DESC) as usage_hour'),
        DB::raw('first_value(data) OVER (PARTITION BY usage_date ORDER BY usage_date DESC, usage_hour DESC) as data')
    ])
    ->get()
```

---

Or it can be done with a subquery (which is inefficient and not cool):

```
SELECT usage_date, max(usage_hour) as usage_hour,
  (SELECT data FROM t AS t2 
   WHERE t2.usage_date = t.usage_date AND t2.usage_hour = max(t.usage_hour) 
  LIMIT 1) AS data
FROM t
GROUP BY usage_date
```

---

If anyone knows a method without subqueries and window functions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let see how it goes

```
$table = \DB::table('table name')->distinct('usage_date')->groupBy('usage_date')->orderBy('usage_hour','desc')->get();
```

Comment: Wrong. It will produce an error `ERROR: column "table_name.data" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Then i guess you are using mysql 5.7.  Its sql_mode is stricter. It works on my machine though. I have altered my sql_mode.

Comment: Actually we were talking about `postgresql`. But I checked your query in `sqlfiddle` and it produces wrong results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb0ae/1

Comment: Oh ok. Never knew it was postgresql.

Comment: I mean your query isn't correct even for `mysql`. Check the sqlfiddle link I gave earlier.

Comment: I get you. But will still check it out.